# Can't access "view" in ArcGIS Javascript API 4.x

Tags: javascript, arcgis

This may just be a formatting issue I hope, but see my simplified version of my index.html and my sourced main.js file. I'm simply trying to create a custom button that acts like the existing zoom button in the ArcGIS JS API mapview.

BUT I keep getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: view is not defined` when it gets to my 'zoomin' Function? I've tried placing the Function throughout my HTML, but it doesn't seem to find `const view = new MapView` in the sourced main.js file?

Where am I going wrong? The .js file seems sourced fine, I should be able to call variables from my index.html to the main.js..correct?

INDEX.HTML

```
    <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>



    <script>

      function zoomin() {
        document.getElementById('zoominbtn')
        console.log('console log')
        var n = view.zoom + 1;
        view.zoom = n;
       };
        
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="myleftnav" class="leftnav">
        <button id="zoominbtn" class=zoominbtn onclick="zoomin()">
            <img src="images/zoom-in-svgrepo-com.svg"width="24" height="24"></button>
    </div>

    <div id="viewDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

MAIN.JS

```
require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView"

], function(Map, MapView) {

var map = new Map({
    basemap: "gray-vector"
});

const view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-100.0, 40.0], // longitude, latitude
    zoom: 3,
    padding: {
        left: 45
    }
});

});
```